# laravel can't read/write compiled blades in storage/framework/views

Tags: laravel-5, php-7, laravel-blade

when I moved my laravel project from local machine to production server, I'm keep getting the following error :

```
(1/1) ErrorException
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/something/storage/framework/views/1a753601712c44f3634dc18d99a244ad1fb3c3b8.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I've tried below possible solutions so far :

```
php artisan cache:clear 
chmod -R 777 storage/
composer dump-autoload
```

my laravel project folder also has required permissions and is owned by apache user.

I've tried a bunch of other possible solutions but nothing worked for me.

my laravel version is 5.5, apache 2.4, centOs 7, php 7.1.14 .

any idea guys?

Comment: Try `php artisan view:clear`, does that change things?

Comment: No, I already tried this command and still getting the error.

Comment: add to the list `route:clear` and `config:clear` just in case, are you running it through `php artisan serve` ? if so, restart this process, also can you `ls -la storage/` and paste it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It might also be an SE Linux issue - you could try temporarily disabling SELinux (enter `setenforce 0` as root).  If that fixes it, you might want to try changing the SELinux security context (enter this from the laravel root directory).

```
chcon -Rv -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage/
```